# How can I obtain historical account balances using QBXML?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I need to obtain the last 24 month-end balances for all accounts in QuickBooks.  Is there a way to do that without running a report (e.g., GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq)?  If not, is there a way to display the ListID values for the accounts in the report output when using the GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq command instead of just the account names?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get this data is via a report.

As far as I know, there's no way to get the ListIDs from the report.

However, if you combine the results of an AccountQuery with the report output, you should be able to determine the ListIDs by matching up the account names from the report with the account names from the AccountQuery.